# C++ lvalues and rvalues

Tags: c++

Ok, so I've been learning about lvalues and rvalues - could somebody well versed in C/C++ tell me if my thinking is correct?

Consider the code:

```
int i = 3;
int j = i;
```

Here we have two lvalues `i` and `j`, when `i` is assigned to `j` it becomes an implicit rvalue because a copy of `i` is stored in `j`.  If however the code looked like:

```
int i = 3;
int j = &i;
```

Would both `j` and `&i` be lvalues because they are both physical addresses in memory?  The way I understand it is that rvalues are temporary data, whereas lvalues have a physical/referenceable memory address.

Any clarification on this would be great!

Comment: I recommend [Strachey (1967)](http://www.itu.dk/courses/BPRD/E2009/fundamental-1967.pdf), section 2.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo - I'll check that reference out now

Comment: @molbdnilo The link is expired. It says: `The requested URL /courses/BPRD/E2009/fundamental-1967.pdf was not found on this server.`

Comment: @RohanBari Imagine that – a web link going stale after just six years. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_Concepts_in_Programming_Languages) is one that should last a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here we have two lvalues `i` and `j`

Yep

> when `i` is assigned to `j` it becomes an implicit rvalue because a copy of `i` is stored in `j`

Not really, `i` is still an lvalue, but it's converted to an rvalue to read its value. This is called an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. `j` is still an lvalue.

> Would both `j` and `&i` be lvalues because they are both physical addresses in memory?

`j` is an lvalue, but `&i` is an rvalue; specifically a prvalue of type `int*`.

Comment: interesting - thanks for the explanation on the fact that `&i` becomes `int*` that makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

The variable `i` never stops being an lvalue. If you can apply the address-of operator to something (like you do in the second example) then it's an lvalue.

Also in the second example `&i` is a *pointer* to `i`, and has the type `int*`. You have a type mismatch there between the declaration of `j` and the value you want to initialize it with.

Lastly, while `i` by itself is a lvalue the expression `&i` is *not* an lvalue, because you can't apply the address-of operator to it (i.e you can't do `&&i`).

Answer (score 4):

Being an *lvalue* or an *rvalue* is a property of an expression. Generally, all expressions which constitute a non-const qualified identifier are *modifiable lvalues*:

```
int i = 5;
i; // the expression "i" is an lvalue and is modifiable

const int j = 3;
j; // the expression "j" is still an lvalue, but not modifiable
```

An lvalue expression (unless qualified with `const`) can be modified through any of the assignment, `++` or `--` operators. You can also apply the `&` "address-of" operator on such an expression.

Some operators like the unary `*`, the array subscript operator `[]`, and the `.` and `->` operators also yield lvalues. This means that you can say, for example, `*p = 3`, or `a[i] = 5`, or `b.c++` or `&c->d`.

On the other hand, expressions which are not lvalues are rvalues (they are temporary and cannot be modified). If you write something like `3 = 5` or `7++`, the compiler will complain that the `3` and `7` subexpressions are not lvalues.

Comment: `they are temporary and cannot be modified` that's not necessarily true. Something like `std::string{} = "hi"`is perfectly valid.